# In haskell is there any difference between a let x= and an x= on the GHCi command line?

Tags: haskell, ghci, let

I'm writing a simple declaration in Haskell GHCi

```
myPi = 3.14
```

I can also write this as

```
let myPi = 3.14
```

Is there any difference for this very simple example between the two declarations? I'm aware of the extra functionality with let, but don't need it here

Comment: A `let` expects an `in`. It scopes the variable locally in the `in` expression. In case of `do` notation, the `in` is implicit, and wraps the remaining lines in the `do`.

Comment: it seems to work without one in GHCi. Should it require one?

Comment: is that in a `do` block?

Comment: It's from the command line

Comment: well the `ghci` has some sort of "implicit" `do` so to speak.

Comment: have adjusted the question. I take it the answer is no?

Comment: The answer depends on where these lines appear exactly. In GHCi there no practical difference.

Comment: Thanks that helps. Not sure why this has been voted down though. Is not using let bad form?

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes were before you edited to be specific about the GHCi context. In "normal" Haskell you normally can't choose between the forms (one or the other is required depending on the context), so the question seemed a bit silly.

Comment: When the optional-`let` feature was new, there were definitely bugs that made them different sometimes. Not sure about now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the GHCi prompt, no, there is no difference.

The `let` used to be required (with the reasoning that the GHCi prompt is a bit like you're entering lines in an `IO` do block). But relatively recently<sup>1</sup> it was updated so that the `let` is optional, in order to provide a more convenient interactive syntax.

---

<sup>1</sup> In [GHC 8.0](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/8.0.1-notes.html#ghci) (the "Added support for top-level function declarations" part). This is old enough that you're very unlikely to be using an older GHCi that requires `let`, but there's still a lot of tutorials and other material around from before that (which don't always tell you clearly what version is being used in their examples). And for some people old habits die hard.

Comment: thanks, that explains why a lot of old tutorials seem to mention it, but it doesn't appear to make any difference

Answer (score 7):

There is a small difference, yes. Under normal operation, ghci accepts one line of input at a time and processes it immediately. However, it also has an "automatic multiline" mode, in which it will try to detect if you want to enter multiple lines at once before processing all of them together. For example, in normal mode:

```
> (3 +
<interactive>:1:5: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
>  case () of
<interactive>:2:1: error:
    Empty list of alternatives in case expression
      Use EmptyCase to allow this
```

After enabling automatic multiline mode with `:set +m` (put that in `~/.ghci` to enable it by default!):

```
> (3 +
| 4)
7
> case () of
|  () -> ()
|
()
```

With that preamble out of the way, I can now tell you what the small difference is: `myPi = 3.14` does not trigger multiline processing, instead defining it immediately; but `let myPi = 3.14` does trigger multiline processing. This can matter, for example, if you want to create mutually recursive bindings; without `let`, they would have to be entered on a single line and separated by explicit semicolons, while with `let` and automatic multiline mode, you could use indentation to separate them in the standard, idiomatic way.

(Additionally, if you are using very old versions of GHC, the non-`let` form may not yet have been available.)

Comment: What are mutually exclusive bindings?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin They are a typo for "mutually recursive bindings"! Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Ah! And here I thought, there would be something new and interesting to learn... :-)